# Regex & PHPUnit assertion : count how many times word matches in repeating pattern

Tags: php, html, phpunit

I'm using PHPUnit to test the output of a PHP function that produces HTML `option` tags using provided data.

For example, this is a correct output of the function (I added line returns to improve readability on SO):

```
<option value="0">Choose one ...</option>
<option value="fooID">fooValue</option>
<option value="barID"selected>barValue</option>
<option value="bazID">bazValue</option>
```

And to test the output, I'm using this assertion:

```
$this->assertRegExp("/(<option value=\".*\" *(selected)? *>.*<\/option>)+/i", $res);
```

where `$res` is the output string of the tested function.

And it works well. But I would like to also check that `selected` is generated in only one `option` tag.

How can I do this? Is there a way to count how many times `selected` was matched?

Thanks in advance, be kind, it's my first question on SO :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use regexes to parse HTML or XML documents. Use a DOM parser:

```
// create a document object from the HTML string
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

// create a XPath selector
$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

// select nodes containing the selected attribute
$result = $selector->query('//*[@selected]');

// make assertion
$this->assertEquals(1, $result->length, 'Failed to assert that result contains exactly one selected element');
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I need to keep my current assertion in addition of this one to ensure that the `option` tags are formatted in the right way, am I right? Can I perform the whole check (in multiple assertions eventually), using only the DOM parser? I must admit I never used those...

Comment: A basic well-formed check is done already by calling `$doc->loadHTML()`. You should assert that the method does not return `false`. Of course you are free to perform additional checks like checking the number of options and the values and ids...

Comment: Thanks for your help! It is really useful to me!